# How do i use --legacy-peer-deps or force in vite build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, frontend, vite

So there's a package called react typed that I used in my project and I had to install it with `--legacy-peer-deps`. for me to deploy, I have to use `vite build`.

When i do, i get

```
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!     react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-typed@1.2.0
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react-typed
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!   react-typed@"^1.2.0" from the root project
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-typed@1.2.0
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/react-typed
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!     react-typed@"^1.2.0" from the root project
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! See /opt/buildhome/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
8:59:31 AM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2023-03-01T07_59_31_432Z-debug-0.log
8:59:31 AM: Error during npm install
8:59:31 AM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
8:59:31 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
8:59:32 AM: Finished processing build request in 7.285s
```

how can I add legacy peer deps or force to the vite build?

I tried using `vite build --legacy-peer-deps`, I expected it to trigger legacy peer deps when installing dependencies although I am not sure if that command exists but it still shows me the same errors.

Comment: react-typed doesn't support React 18, you can't do anything about this, so if you want to use react-typed, you have to install React 16. Or contribute to react-typed by either supporting this issue (https://github.com/ssbeefeater/react-typed/issues/59) or implementing React 18 support yourself. Forcing installation is not recommended as you have no idea what will work and what won't.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `npm config set legacy-peer-deps=true` command or create a `.npmrc` file in the root directory and add `legacy-peer-deps=true` inside